# How to use sqlite3's .import from android code

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm creating an android app that uses a sqlite database. I have csv files that I would like to include in the build and use for initial population of the database. I've seen that SQLite has a .import command to import a csv file to a certain table. While its easy to run this from the command line, I really want to run it in SQLiteOpenHelper's onCreate(), perhaps using this code:

```
String[] cmd = {"sqlite3", "database.db", ".import " + path + " tableName"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Problem is: how do I get the path to the csv? Will this work?

Comment: Its not my choice unfortunately.

Comment: Its the files that have been provided to me by my company and I have no other choice? :P